# Unable to Boot Centos 8 from external SSD, as the system does not show up in boot list

Tags: linux, centos, dual-boot

I have recently started studying for RHCSA, and thought of installing the Centos os on external drive and booting from it as I am using windows for daily use.

But when I try to boot from the external SSD it does not sow up on bootable media list and also not in the bios. After a fresh install it does show up until the SDD is connected but after connecting and disconnecting it does not show up again.

I have tried changing from UEFI to Legacy, disabling Fast Boot and secure boot, changing ports and boot order, even tried easyBCD in a last attempt but no result.

[image: Bios Boot Config]

[image: Available Options for Boot media]

none of the above option are detecting the external SSD

Comment: UEFI system? UEFI install? ESP - efi system partition on external drive with grub's boot files? External drives actually only boot from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which is same filename as live installer. Should be shown as UEFI:XXX boot entry for external drive.

Comment: I can see the mentioned directory and file but it is still not being picked up, it works as normal when I do a clean install but as soon as i shutdown and disconnect the ssd, it stops recognising the ssd as bootable media on next run

Comment: If an external drive, and you are seeing the grub/Centos entry, it is removed when you disconnect a drive. UEFI forgets entries for removed drives. But the default boot entry of bootx64.efi will still work. It will just be the drive entry not  a specific install entry.

Comment: tried booting from other options as well ( USB HDD ) even disabled the windows boot manager from the bios but still no luck, do I have to setup the external drive in a specific way or is there some issue with bios.

Comment: When manually booting an external drive, the selection in UEFI boot menu usually overrides the default boot setting of UEFI or CSM/BIOS in UEFI settings. Unless Secure boot is on, then USB boot may not be allowed unless another setting to allow USB boot is also on. Check various UEFI settings. I would expect USB hard drive entry to work if /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi in the ESP system partition on external drive.You do have ESP partition on external?

Answer (score 1):

Two easy ways to do this on UEFI system. In both cases, you'll need to have two partitions (at least): one for root (Linux type...but I would recommend using the Linux root type in GUID) and one for EFI. I presume that the CentOS install already created both.

The first way to boot would be to use the UEFI shell. For this, you'll need the shellx64.efi file (available for download). You should be able to set your system to boot from a file. Direct it to the shellx64.efi file on your EFI partition. That will drop you into the UEFI shell, from which you can boot using any nsh file (the default is a startup.nsh).

The second way has been pointed to in other texts. You can create a bootx64.efi file (using dracut, for example). That file, placed on the EFI partition in the EFI/BOOT directory, will be the first file looked for by the UEFI system. When it is seen, your USB drive should be listed in the boot menu.

There's not much written in detail about these approaches, but I use both routinely and they work with every UEFI I've ever encountered.